# ¿Cómo cambiar el nombre del campo email al recuperar contraseña en Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel

He usado la autenticación y recuperación de contraseña proporcionado por laravel 5.3, haciendo uso del comando `php artisan make:auth`, en mi base de datos mi tabla usuario posee el campo `usua_correo` y `usua_contrasena` para iniciar sesión, al momento de hacer uso de la funcionalidad de recuperar contraseña me arroja lo siguiente:

> QueryException in Connection.php line 770: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not
>   found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select *
>   from `Usuario` where `email` = usuario@usuario.com limit 1)

No he encontrado la manera de que en vez de usar el campo `email` en el where de la consulta, use el campo `usua_correo`

He intentado con las siguientes funciones en `User.php` (modelo)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * El nombre de la tabla asociada al modelo.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'Usuario';

    /**
     * El nombre de la llave primaria de la tabla.
     * Se modifica debido a que no es el nombre por defecto: id.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'usua_id';

    /**
     * El nombre del campo equivalente a CREATE_AT en la base de datos.
     * Se modifica debido a que no es el nombre por defecto: create_at.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const CREATED_AT = 'usua_fechacreacion';

    /**
     * El nombre del campo equivalente a UPDATED_AT en la base de datos.
     * Se modifica debido a que no es el nombre por defecto: update_at.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const UPDATED_AT = 'usua_fechamodificacion';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'usua_nombre', 'usua_correo', 'usua_contrasena','usua_rol'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'usua_contrasena', 'remember_token',
    ];

    // 1
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->usua_contrasena;
    }

    // 2
    public function getEmailForPasswordReset() {
        return $this->usua_correo;
    }

    // 3
    public function getUserNameForPasswordReset(){
        return $this->usua_correo;
    }

    // 4
    protected $email = "usua_correo";
}
```

Vista `email.blade.php`

```
@extends('general.template.main')
@section('title', 'Cambiar Contraseña')


<!-- Main Content -->
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">{{ trans('messages.restablecer_contrasena') }}</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/password/email') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label" >{{ trans('messages.correo') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                  {{ trans('messages.enviar_contrasena') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Compártenos el código de tu vista del formulario de reinicio de clave, por favor.

Comment: Hola @Shaz muchas gracias por mirar mi pregunta, ya he actualizado el código con la clase completa para **User.php** y para la vista **email.blade.php**. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta cambiando el campo en la vista y sobreescribir la validación al momento de recibir el Request en el controlador de autenticación, algo así debería funcionar o al menos estar muy cerca de tu objetivo:

Vista:

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('usua_correo') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label" >{{ trans('messages.correo') }}</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="usua_correo" type="email" class="form-control" name="usua_correo" value="{{ old('usua_correo') }}" required>

        @if ($errors->has('usua_correo'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('usua_correo') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

No recuerdo si los controladores de autenticación fueron divididos a partir de 5.3 o 5.4, en todo caso, al menos en 5.4 sería en el controlador `ForgotPasswordController`, el cual probablemente esté localizado en `app\Http\Controllers\Auth`:

```
/**
 * Send a reset link to the given user.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['usua_correo' => 'required|email']);

    // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
    // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
    // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
    $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
        $request->only('usua_correo')
    );

    return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($response)
                : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
}
```

Comment: Hola @Shaz , creo que tu ejemplo de código me ha funcionado para dejar de visualizar el error del campo email en la consulta, pero así como usé una tabla **Usuario** propia, también estoy usando una tabla **PasswordReset** propia llamada: **RestablecerContrasena**, con los siguientes campos: 

**reco_correo** ,
**reco_token** ,
**reco_fechacreacion**  y
**reco_fechamodificacion**

y me arroja el siguiente error:
`SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'simuladorcontable.password_resets' doesn't exist (SQL: delete from `password_resets` where `email` is null)`

Comment: Bueno, he encontrado que modificando **config/app.php** en la posición de **'passwords'** se logra establecer la tabla para restablecer la contraseña, pero no encuentro la manera de cambiarle el campo email. Tengo el siguiente error:
`Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: delete from `RestablecerContrasena` where `email` is null)`

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que sobrescribir varios de los métodos del trait "ResetsPasswords" en el archivo PasswordsController.php

En lugar de hacer esto te recomiendo que sigas las convenciones de Laravel, va a ser más fácil en el futuro mantener el proyecto y será también mucho mas fácil para otros programadores entender el código.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Jeff, creo que adecuaré mi proyecto para que al menos en el manejo de usuarios se use como lo trae laravel por defecto.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes cambiar de esta forma tambien.

```
public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate(request(), 
        [
            'email' => 'required'
        ], 
        [
            'email.required' => 'El "Correo Electrónico" es obligatorio.',
        ]);
  
    $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink([ 'email' => 'email@prueba.com']);
}
```